# Swift xcode error "cannot subscript a value of type '[ListOfAnimals]'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here is a screenshot of the class where I got the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOmlM.png

I'm not sure exactly what a subscript means even though at first I thought it meant that it was an existing member of a class.

Here is the first class

```
import UIKit
class AnimalListTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController, let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            detailViewController.animal = animals[indexPath.row] //This is where I get the error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[ListOfAnimals]'
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the ListOfAnimals class

```
import UIKit


let animals = [
    ListOfAnimals(name: "Cow",
        shortDescription: "Cattle",
        longDescription: "A cow is a mature female and bull of an adult male of a bovine family. A heifer is a female cow that hasn't had a calf yet. Cattle is the name for the whole cow family. THere are about 920 different breeds of cows in the world."),

    ListOfAnimals(name: "Bird",
        shortDescription: "Usually small, has wings, feathers, and can fly.",
        longDescription: "A warm-blooded egg-laying vertebrate distinguished by the possession of feathers, wings, and a beak and (typically) by being able to fly."),

    ListOfAnimals(name: "Dolphin",
        shortDescription: "A large fish",
        longDescription: "A small gregarious toothed whale that typically has a beaklike snout and a curved fin on the back. Dolphins have become well known for their sociable nature and high intelligence."),

    ListOfAnimals(name: "Dog",
        shortDescription: "Man's best friend",
        longDescription: "A domesticated carnivorous mammal that typically has a long snout, an acute sense of smell, and a barking, howling, or whining voice. It is widely kept as a pet or for work or field sports."),

    ListOfAnimals(name: "Zebra",
        shortDescription: "A horse with white and black stripes",
        longDescription: "an African wild horse with black-and-white stripes and an erect mane."),

]

class ListOfAnimals
{


    var name: String
    //var type: Type
    var shortDescription: String
    var longDescription: String

    init(name: String, shortDescription: String, longDescription: String)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.shortDescription = shortDescription
        self.longDescription = longDescription
    }

}
```

Here is the Animal Class

```
import UIKit

class Animal
{
    var animal = Animal.self
    var name: String


    var shortDescription: String
    var longDescription: String
    init(name: String, shortDescription: String, longDescription: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.shortDescription = shortDescription
        self.longDescription = longDescription

    }

}
```

EDIT: When I use “animals?[indexPath.row]", I get this error: "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type ‘[ListOfAnimals]’” ..... but then When I use "animals![indexPath.row]”, I get this error: “Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '[ListOfAnimals]’”.....but then When I use "animals[indexPath.row]”, I get this error: “Cannot Subscript a value of type ‘[ListOfAnimals]’”.....but then I was using that line "var animal = Animal.self" because I was paranoid that if I didn't use it, the compiler would just complain and say animal wasn't initialized or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: With your latest code changes, `Animal` should be `animals`. `Animal` is the name of the class, whereas you are trying to index one of the animals.

Is `animals` only declared once? The error message suggests that in your first class, `animals` is Optional, in which case you would have to suffix it with '?' or '!'. However, your ListOfAnimals class shows it is non-Optional, if that's the same reference.

```
 // If animals is non-Optional...
let animal = animals[indexPath.row]

 // If animals is Optional
let animal = animals?[indexPath.row]

 // If animals is Optional, but you know it's non-nil
let animal = animals![indexPath.row]
```

Nevertheless, on a general note, it's not clear why ListOfAnimals exists. It looks like you want to get one animal in AnimalListTableViewController from an array of animals. Therefore I would expect:

```
let animals = [Animal(...), Animal(...), Animal(...), Animal(...)]
```

And also your `numberOfRowsInSection` to return `animals.count`. The above `let` would then be in `AnimalListTableViewController`, and `ListOfAnimals` therefore doesn't need to exist.

It is also not clear why you need the following line:

```
var animal = Animal.self
```

Comment: When I use “animals?[indexPath.row]", I get this error: "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type ‘[ListOfAnimals]’”

..... but then When I use "animals![indexPath.row]”, I get this error: “Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '[ListOfAnimals]’”.....but then

When I use "animals[indexPath.row]”, I get this error: “Cannot Subscript a value of type ‘[ListOfAnimals]’”.....but then

I was using that line "var animal = Animal.self" because I was paranoid that if I didn't use it, the compiler would just complain and say animal wasn't initialized or something like that.

Comment: I suggest you delete the ListOfAnimals class as I suggested, and just use Animal. You won't need a `var animal` inside animal, so you should delete that line too.

Comment: Ok so after deleting that class I got another error on the same line of code that said "Type 'Animal.Type' has no subscript members." How do I create a subscript member for it?.

Comment: Can you update your question to show how your code stands now. The implication is that your `animals` now contains a reference to a class, rather than an array of animals.

Comment: I'm hesitant to delete the animals[] array because the animals[] array is supposed to represent a list, where in each row is one animal then the user clicks it and then the user is transported to a new window and the window then shows a description of the animal but I'm not sure what class I should put it in

Comment: Don't delete `animals`. The line `detailViewController.animal = Animal[indexPath.row]` should be `detailViewController.animal = animals[indexPath.row]`